# Initialization issue in Swift 2

Tags: swift, initialization, swift2

I was working on a game with Swift 1 and Xcode 6 and everything was working perfectly. But when I updated to XCode 7 and Swift 2, I was getting a weird issue. In my game I had some NSTimers saved in variables to spawn the enemies. An example of one of this variables was something like this:

```
var firstTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(actualTime, target: self, selector: Selector("SpawnEnemy"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

When I updated, every variable of this type (I had like 4) got an issue that says: "*Initialization of variable "firstTimer" was never used; consider replacing with assignment to "_" or removing it.*"

I can't just change every variable's name to "_", and I never had to initialize it.
What is going on? And why didn't this happened before?

*btw: I do use this variables in the code.*

Comment: How are you invalidating your timers if you aren't keeping a reference to it? That's a potential memory leak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says it all, you didn't use the value in your code at all. If you intend to never stop the timer, you can just omit the declaration of the variable like this:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(actualTime, target: self, selector: Selector("SpawnEnemy"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

But if you want to stop it later you should probably save it:

```
class MyViewController {
    var timer : NSTimer?

    func startTimer() {
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(actualTime, target: self, selector: Selector("SpawnEnemy"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func stopTimer() {
        timer?.invalidate()
    }
}
```

What you can do:

- `var timer = ...` gives a warning that you didn't use the value (if you didn't) and a warning that `timer` never changed and should be a `let`.
- `let timer = ...` gives a warning that you didn't use the value (if you didn't)
- `let _ = ...` same as `_ = ...` evaluates the right-hand side and discards the result. No warnings
- Just `...` does the same as the last one, but can give a warning on functions with the `@warn_unused_result` attribute when the result isn't used.

Comment: 2) Why this didn't happen before

Comment: @Gabe12 (1) You never reference the variable `firstTimer` in your code… if you did, the warning wouldn't appear (2) because this is a new warning

Comment: Then how do I reference the variable? with the example above? I'm sorry, I'm just beginning to program games.

Comment: Do you need to reference the variable? Do you want the timer to ever stop? (If you want to reference the variable, follow the pattern in this answer. If you don't, use `_` or just omit the assignment entirely, as described in this answer.)

Comment: You are right, sorry for being so stubborn I was so frustrated